# firebase authentication with create user with email

Tags: react-native

I am trying to build an authentication using createUserWithEmailAndPassword. It keeps throwing this error
firebase.auth is not a function. (In 'firebase.auth()', 'firebase.auth' is undefined

```
registerUser = () => {
    if (this.state.email === '' && this.state.password === '') {
      Alert.alert('Enter details to signup!');
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: true,
      });
      firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
        .then((res) => {
          res.user.updateProfile({
            displayName: this.state.displayName,
          });
          console.log('User registered successfully!');
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            displayName: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
          });
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
        })
        .catch((error) => this.setState({errorMessage: error.message}));
    }
  };
```

Comment: I think setup is not done properly. Refer this blog
https://pramodkumar-005.medium.com/react-native-authentication-via-email-using-firebase-35e7f9e52bfe